# How to send email without chooser dialog, by default email client?

Tags: android, email, email-client

I would like to send a email through default email client,without chooser dialog for email clients been popped up in the application.Kindly help me with a snippet or example on this regard.Thank you.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894774/detecting-the-target-application-when-sending-an-intent

Comment: Look up the definition of explicit intents vs. implicit intents. What you want is an explicit intent. The link posted by Pankaj is not relevant here.

Comment: See [Send Email in background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19947819/3317558)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to launch a specific application, you use an *explicit* `Intent`, instead of an *implicit* one.

However, there is no such thing as a *default*  email client in Android. Many manufacturers, eg Samsung install their own one, and some people use that, some use Gmail.

Android already has a way to let the user set the default via the Chooser dialog, so I would recommend you to rely on that.