# Get IntentSender object for createChooser method in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I would like to use new version of [Intent.createChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender)) method which uses `IntentSender`.

Documentation states only that I can grab it from `PendingIntent` instance. In my case it seems that `PendingIntent` won't have any other use.

Is there another way to obtain `IntentSender` or do I need create `PendingIntent`?

Comment: you have to create it through the `PendingIntent`. The constructors are public but annotate with `@hide`

Comment: @Blackbelt but should I pass `PendingIntent` as target `Intent`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The chooser target intent is not a `PendingIntent`. For instance, in the following snippet, I am declaring intent for  `ACTION_SEND`, with type `text/plain`, and this is the my target intent for the `Intent.createChooser`. Then I am creating another `Intent`, receiver, and a handler, the `PendingIntent`, which will invoke `onReceive` of my BroadcastReceiver after the user picks something from the chooser.

```
// Set up the broadcast receiver (preferably as a class member)
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // Unregister self right away
         context.unregisterReceiver(this);

         // Component will hold the package info of the app the user chose
         ComponentName component = intent.getParcelableExtra<ComponentName>(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT);
         // Do something with component
     }
}


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
intent.setType("text/plain");

// Use custom action only for your app to receive the broadcast
final String shareAction = "com.yourdomain.share.SHARE_ACTION";
Intent receiver = new Intent(shareAction);
receiver.putExtra("test", "test");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "test", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());

// Before firing chooser activity, register the receiver with our custom action from above so that we receive the chosen app
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SHARE_ACTION));

startActivity(chooser);
```

**Edit**:

The information, in the case of the `BroadcastReceiver` is embedded in the intent you get as parameter. After you selected one of the option, retrieve the Bundle's extras and using the key `Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT`, you should be able to find what the user picked.

Try adding as simple *Log.d* to `onReceive`

```
for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
}
```

In my example I got

`ComponentInfo{org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity}`

for `Telegram` and

```
ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.inbox/com.google.android.apps.bigtop.activities.ComposeMessageActivity}
```

for `InBox`

Comment: Ok and how to get info what choice was taken by user? Documentation states `The caller may optionally supply an IntentSender to receive a callback when the user makes a choice. This can be useful if the calling application wants to remember the last chosen target and surface it as a more prominent or one-touch affordance elsewhere in the UI for next time.`

Comment: don't forget to add your broadcast register class to your manifest

Comment: Is there any code sample that I can take a look how to do this? My broadcast receiver doesn't receive anything.

Comment: My broadcast receiver also isn't working. Could you please show how you hooked up the broadcast receiver? I am registering it in my activity but am not sure what to use for the intent filter.

Comment: what we do , when api level is bellow than 22

Comment: Can we see `BroadcastTest.class` implementation?

Comment: not receiving the broadcast in Android 9.0. It is working in 7.0

Comment: Not receiving test extra parameter in onReceive

Comment: 1. this createChooser available on API >= 22

2. the approach doesn't work for me. onReceive is called immidiately when chooser opens and not calling when select some app from chooser.

Comment: I improved the example code snippet to include also the setup of a broadcast receiver

Comment: use this to receive broadcast context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(shareAction));

Comment: You'll probably also want to unregister the broadcastReceiver in `onResume()` or else if the user hits the back button when the share sheet appears then does an action to create another broadcastReceiver, you'll end up with multiple.

Comment: Also note, your `PendingIntent` flag should be `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: @ShintaS how do you add your broadcast register class to your manifest ? Thanks

Comment: onReceive is called, but component is always null for me. Tried on different OS versions

Comment: @AleksandrUrzhumtcev use PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE instead of PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE as James as mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it.

```
    /**
     * Receiver to record the chosen component when sharing an Intent.
     */
    static class TargetChosenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String EXTRA_RECEIVER_TOKEN = "receiver_token";
        private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

        private static String sTargetChosenReceiveAction;
        private static TargetChosenReceiver sLastRegisteredReceiver;

        static boolean isSupported() {
            return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        static void sendChooserIntent(Activity activity, Intent sharingIntent) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (sTargetChosenReceiveAction == null) {
                    sTargetChosenReceiveAction = activity.getPackageName() + "/"
                            + TargetChosenReceiver.class.getName() + "_ACTION";
                }
                Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
                if (sLastRegisteredReceiver != null) {
                    context.unregisterReceiver(sLastRegisteredReceiver);
                }
                sLastRegisteredReceiver = new TargetChosenReceiver();
                context.registerReceiver(
                        sLastRegisteredReceiver, new IntentFilter(sTargetChosenReceiveAction));
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(sTargetChosenReceiveAction);
            intent.setPackage(activity.getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER_TOKEN, sLastRegisteredReceiver.hashCode());
            final PendingIntent callback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                    activity.getString(R.string.share_link_chooser_title),
                    callback.getIntentSender());
            activity.startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (sLastRegisteredReceiver != this) return;
                context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(sLastRegisteredReceiver);
                sLastRegisteredReceiver = null;
            }
            if (!intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER_TOKEN)
                    || intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RECEIVER_TOKEN, 0) != this.hashCode()) {
                return;
            }

            ComponentName target = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT);
            if (target != null) {
                setLastShareComponentName(context, target);
            }
        }
    }
```